# Is "Create Table" or "Create Any Table" Privilages grant the user a quota implicitly?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on our database users privileges, and I am facing a confusing issue. I first created a user (user1) without any quota and grant him the role CONNECT which have the system privilege (Create Session). After that I grant him the (Create Table) privilege. The user try to create a table and he succeeded to create a table in his tablespace!! my questions are:

1. Based on my understanding, the user must have a quota to create any objects, how this user created the table?
2. Is there any privilege or roles that give the user a quota implicitly?

Regards,

Comment: Could you share the `CREATE USER` statement?

Comment: CREATE USER USER1
  IDENTIFIED BY <password>
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE USER1
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
  PROFILE DEFAULT
  ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
  -- 1 Role for USER1 
  GRANT CONNECT TO USER1;
  -- 1 System Privilege for USER1 
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO USER1;

Comment: Were they able to insert into the table? I suspect this is just deferred segment creation. You don't need a quota to create objects, but you do if they require any storage - the question here is whether storage was needed immediately when the table was created.

Comment: Interesting!! the user cannot insert into the table and the message (ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USER1') is shown. I also checked the DEFERRED_SEGMENT_CREATION parameter and its was TRUE. So, the database will tell the user that his table is created even though he has no quota!! I think its not very practical..

Comment: The table is created though, so it exists in the data dictionary and can be queried. There may be situations where an application has many tables and code that expects them all to exist; but a particular installation of the application only uses a subset of the functionality and lots of tables would remain empty. Creating them without initial segments saves space, at least until they are populated. If they will never be populated then they never need a quota. They could all be grouped into a small dummy tablespace, perhaps. In your situation it doesn't seem useful though, I agree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quota isn't being granted implicitly. But creating a table doesn't necessarily require any storage, and so doesn't necessarily require a quota:

```
create table t42 (id number);

Table T42 created.

select segment_type, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

no rows selected
```

Adding data to the table does require storage, and therefore a quota:

```
insert into t42 (id) values (1);

1 row inserted.

select segment_type, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

SEGMENT_TYPE            BYTES
------------------ ----------
TABLE                   65536
```

If the owner doesn't have a quota on the tablespace then they will get an error when they try to insert; which is the case when they do have a quota and try to exceed it too of course (though the error will be different).

This behaviour is due to deferred segment creation; the default behaviour is controlled by [an initialisation parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/initparams075.htm#REFRN10307). You can override that during table creation [with the segment creation clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CEGBDDBC).

```
drop table t42 purge;

Table T42 dropped.

create table t42 (id number) segment creation immediate;

Table T42 created.

select segment_type, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

SEGMENT_TYPE            BYTES
------------------ ----------
TABLE                   65536
```

[Read more in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CEGJHDEB).

---

Incidentally, if you create a table with deferred segment creation then `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` shows that; if you then insert a row to force a segment to be created, `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` changes to `SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE`. Which might not be expected. Truncating the table with the `DROP ALL STORAGE` clause will remove the segments, and revert the DDL to `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED`. Just something I noticed in passing.